# Order string[] path from filename c#

Tags: c#, string

I have a problem with my software, I need to order a series of .mp4 video that are located in different folders.

Now I'm able to retrieve all videos with this instruction:

```
string[] video = Directory.GetFiles("..\\..\\", "*.mp4", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

But I have not my video ordered by name, they are ordered by folder.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: This is just my opinion: If you have folders on your directory, as a default this search based on folders order, then files order.

Comment: As  a side note if you're in .NET 4.0 or above better `Directory.EnumerateFiles`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
 video.OrderBy(Path.GetFileName).ToArray();
```

Comment: Hamlet, you don't need the lambda. Thank you though

Comment: I never get why people call the .ToArray() or .ToList() by default. What if he is only interested in the first. .ToArray() will iterate them all.

Comment: Yes, but using method group not intuitively understandably.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen - GetFiles returns a string array, if you wanted to apply to the same variable then it also needs to be an array. Hamlet, I find this just as readable now im used to it

Comment: @Sayse - So people like to return what the initial variable-type was.

Comment: Wouldn't work for `{ @"c:\path1\file2", @"c:\path2\file1", @"c:\path1\file1" }`

Comment: @QtX - it's only about the filename, not the full path.

Comment: Op already has returned mp4 files. @jeroen van langen it just stops the inevitable second question of why it isn't working

Comment: @QtX Why wouldn't it? per the "original specifications" in the OP two files with the same name but in different folders would fall under "Undefined Behavior". Now if it where me, I would want a deterministic ordering for situations like that even though it is not "part of the spec" so what I would do would be `video.OrderBy(Path.GetFileName).ThenBy(x => x)` which would use the folder ordering if there was a tie in the file naming.

Answer (score 2):

add the following using statement to your code:

```
using System.Linq;
```

then you can order the array by string:

```
video = video.OrderBy(x => Path.GetFileName(x)).ToArray();
```

Comment: This will still sort by the full path.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
var ordered = video.OrderBy(filename => Path.GetFilename(filename));
```